# How to retrieve data annotation strings from Database > Resource File in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

In ASP.NET MVC5 we''re using Resource files which are great for allowing providing translations across applications. This works well for Annotations aswell.

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "ROLE", ResourceType = typeof(AdminRes))]
    public string UserRole { get; set; }
```

The strings for the Annotations are currently stored in Resource-Files.

But what I want to achieve is the following: I want to check a database if a certain string (i.e. "ROLE") exists. If it does, I want to use it as `[Display(Name = "string")`. If there was no such string found, I want to use the existing Resource-File as alternative and get the string from there.

Any plain idea how to get this working?

Comment: Consider performance penalty as a result of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like this:

Added my own CustomModelMetadataProvider...

```
public class CustomModelMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    private DynamicStringService DynamicStringService;
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes,
          Type containerType, Func<object> modelAccessor,
          Type modelType, string propertyName)
    {
        var modelMetadata = base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType,
                modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);


        List<DisplayAttribute> list = attributes.OfType<DisplayAttribute>().ToList();
        foreach (DisplayAttribute d in list)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.Name))
            {
                try
                {
                    DynamicStringService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<DynamicStringService>();
                    Language userLanguage = GetCurrentUILanguage();

                    string changingValue = DynamicStringService.ChangeName(d.Name, userLanguage);
                    modelMetadata.DisplayName = changingValue;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        return modelMetadata;
    }
}
```

..where DynamicStringService checks the database for the String in the Annotation [Display].

The CustomModelMetadataProvider is used in the Globasl.asax.cs in Application_Start() like this:

```
ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new CustomModelMetadataProvider();
```